# Regex: to match unsigned integer values (valid values: 0 to 65535 only) for comma separated values

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have

```
([0-5]?\d?\d?\d?\d|6[0-4]\d\d\d|65[0-4]\d\d|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-5])
```

which works for single input as:

```
0
1
65
6553
```

but i want them for comma separated input string as:

`0,1,65,6553`  ->this is a valid string
`65535,-1,25`  ->this is a invalid string because of negative number.

please can anyone suggest solution

Note:

```
I have already tried repetition as:
^([0-5]?\d?\d?\d?\d|6[0-4]\d\d\d|65[0-4]\d\d|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-5])+(,(([0-5]?\d?\d?\d?\d|6[0-4]\d\d\d|65[0-4]\d\d|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-5])))*$
```

which is accepting 65537 also which is undesirable.

Comment: The first example pattern works the way you described when the global modifier is set.

Comment: The plus in `)+(,` should not be there (halfway your last regex): you don't want the first part to repeat; any "repetition" should be achieved with the second half of the regex, not the first.

Comment: If you want to match only a range of integer values, regex might not be the best choice to do so.
You may want to use a regex to get all integers in your string, and check their values afterwards.

Comment: Why using regex for such job?

Answer (score 0):

Checking number bounds afterwards seems more straightforward to me, but anyway, this is a regex you may use (I refactored the integer part a little bit)

`^(([0-5]?\d{0,4}|6[0-4]\d{3}|65[0-4]\d{2}|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-5])(,|(?=$)))+$`

https://regex101.com/r/1RpNuy/1

Details:

- `^` : String start
- `(` : Group start

  - `([0-5]?\d{0,4}|6[0-4]\d{3}|65[0-4]\d{2}|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-5])` : Match a number
  - `(,|(?=$))` : Match either `,` or make sure this is end of line (but without reading the `$`)
- `)+` : End of group, repeat as many times as possible
- `$` : End of string

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^(?:\d{1,4}|[1-5]\d{4}|6[0-4]\d{3}|65[0-4]\d{2}|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-5])(?:,(?:\d{1,4}|[1-5]\d{4}|6[0-4]\d{3}|65[0-4]\d{2}|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-5]))*$
```

In PCRE and Onigmo, you may use a shorter pattern where `\g<1>` repeated Group 1 pattern:

```
^(\d{1,4}|[1-5]\d{4}|6[0-4]\d{3}|65[0-4]\d{2}|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-5])(?:,\g<1>)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AdMtOi/1/) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/AdMtOi/4/)

The regex is basically `^<BLOCK>(?:,<BLOCK>)*$` where the *BLOCK* pattern is a regex matching the numbers from `0` to `65535`:

- `\d{1,4}` - 1, 2, 3 or 4 digits (`0` - `9999`)
- `[1-5]\d{4}` - `1` to `5` digit and then any 4 digits (`10000` - `50000`)
- `6[0-4]\d{3}`  - `6`, then a digit from `0` to `4`, and then three digits (`60000` - `64999`)
- `65[0-4]\d{2}` - `65`, a digit from `0` to `4` and then any two digits (`65000` - `65499`)
- `655[0-2]\d` - `655`, a digit from `0` to `2` and then any digit (`65500` - `655299`)
- `6553[0-5]` - `6553` and then a digit from `0` to `5` (`65530` - `65535`)

The general pattern:

- `^` - start of string
- `<BLOCK>` - BLOCK pattern described above
- `(?:,<BLOCK>)*` - 0 or more repetitions of `,` and then BLOCK pattern
- `$` - end of string.